# jQuery count amount of divs on a page and hide?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide

I'm displaying an amount of divs on a page that can be anywhere from 1-50, all will be generated and loaded into the HTML via PHP, but I want to only display 9 initially and then load an additional 9 on a button click until all are loaded.

```
   var alldivs = $('.preview-container').hide();

$('button').on('click', function(){
    var turn = alldivs.splice(0, 9);
    if (turn.length) {
        console.log(turn);
        turn.fadeIn();
    }
});
```

Comment: Add the code you've attempted.

Comment: Load only the initial 9 and then load the rest.

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: The divs will already be loaded, i need to initially hide all apart from 9, and then display 9 more each time the button is clicked until all are shown, but I can't figure out how it can be done

Comment: Can you show the html corresponding to `$('.preview-container')` ? I'm almost sure it should be `$('.preview-container div')`

Comment: <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 preview-container">

Comment: Try using `console.log(alldivs)` right after setting it

Answer (score 1):

This is the shortest code I can think to do this:

```
var alldivs = $('div'); // select the elements you want to show here

$('button').on('click', function(){
    var turn = alldivs.splice(0, 9);
    if (turn.length) {
        turn.fadeIn();
    }
});
```

As the jQuery-selector returns an array with the matched elements you can combine that with the [Array splice method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to do what you want.

Basically `alldivs.splice(0, 9)` remove nine items starting at position zero from `alldivs` and returns the removed items.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Shouldn't that be: `$('div:not(:visible)')` ?  to load the next 9

Comment: @freedomn-m. Actually `$('div')` is just an example... the OP probably has a class or something to the divs he wants to fadeIn.. the idea is that the jQuery selector returns an array and you can combine that with splice-method.

Comment: Right - so if he wants 10-18, then use `alldivs.splice(10,18).fadeIn()` - might be worth adding something along those lines to your answer.   I liked the use of `splice` here.

Comment: 544 Uncaught TypeError: turn.fadeIn is not a function?

Comment: @user3574766. Strange because the `if()` should avoid `fadeIn` when there is no more elements... Could you add `console.log(turn);` before `turn.fadeIn()` and tell me what it shows?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: alldivs.splice is not a function

I get that before I can console.log?

Comment: @user3574766. Have you typed `var alldivs = $('div');` before the click-function?

Comment: Apologies, it returns the first 9 divs now,

Array[9]
0
:
div.col-md-4.col-sm-6.col-xs-12.preview-container
1
:
div.col-md-4.col-sm-6.col-xs-12.preview-container
2
:
div.col-md-4.col-sm-6.col-xs-12.preview-container
3
:
div.col-md-4.col-sm-6.col-xs-12.preview-container
4
:
div.col-md-4.col-sm-6.col-xs-12.preview-container
5
:
div.col-md-4.col-sm-6.col-xs-12.preview-container
6
:
div.col-md-4.col-sm-6.col-xs-12.preview-container
7
:
div.col-md-4.col-sm-6.col-xs-12.preview-container
8
:
div.col-md-4.col-sm-6.col-xs-12.preview-container
length
:
9
__proto__
:
Array[0]

Comment: @user3574766. Is it working as expected now? Nine divs at time?

Comment: All the divs are still being displayed on page load unfortunatley

Comment: @user3574766. Change `var alldivs = $('div');` to `var alldivs = $('div').hide();` just to be sure

Comment: Now none are displayed, on click of show more button I get "(index):545 Uncaught TypeError: turn.fadeIn is not a function" I will update the code in the question to reflect what I have now

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very vague. For a better reference, you need to post your current code, what precisely you need to do and what you have searched so far. So it can help you to receive a better answer. But most likely you are looking for something like this:

```
$('li').click(function() {
    var which = $(this).index();
    $('div').find('div').hide().eq(which).show();
});
```