# Show only next 10 divs

Tags: jquery, html

I have a list with generated divs like this:

```
<div class="news-loaded">...</div>
<div class="news-loaded">...</div>
<div class="news-loaded">...</div>
<div class="news-loaded">...</div>
etc.
```

On scroll I want to fade in 10 divs and show a fake loader.

For now I have this code:

```
$(window).scroll( function(){
    $('.ajax-loader').each( function(i){

        var bottom_of_object = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
        var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
        if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object ){
            $('.news-loaded').fadeIn(300);  
        }

    }); 

});
```

So if the ajax loader div is visible it now loads ALL divs but I just want to load the next few divs.

Comment: Check [.offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) on how to check if an element is at a specific position within the document. Your current selector will not check the positioning of the divs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure there's lots of ways, but I tend to use [slice()](http://api.jquery.com/slice/).

In your case, the following might do the trick:

Replace: `$('.news-loaded').fadeIn(300);`

With:

```
$('.news-loaded').slice(0, 9).fadeIn(300);
```

**EDIT:** Credit to [freedomn-m](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2181514/freedomn-m) for this enhanced version of the above:

```
$('.news-loaded').not(':visible').slice(0, 9).fadeIn(300);
```

Comment: Change to `$('.news-loaded').not(':visible').slice(0, 9).fadeIn(300);` and you don't need to track which have already been shown.

Comment: Thanks, amazing! One last question: how Can I check if all elements are visible? So I can hide the ajax loader

Comment: `if ($('.news-loaded').not(':visible').length == 0)` = none are not visible = all are visible

Comment: @freedomn-m thanks for the improved version - I should've spent more time thinking about that.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: Found the one I was thinking was a duplicate, but that started at your end point (and isn't a very good quality question), so not a duplicate.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36040728/jquery-count-amount-of-divs-on-a-page-and-hide/36040818